# react-redux: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, react-redux, fetch-api

So, I tried to fetch data from API using axios, when I 'npm start' on my front end code, it returns Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. I have tried to figure it out what's the problem, But I have no idea.

Here is my back-end code:

```
// //config
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }
)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  next();
})


const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', ()=> console.log('connected'))

const gasRouter = require('./routes/gas-routes')
app.use('/api/gas', gasRouter)

const stockRouter = require('./routes/stock-routes')
app.use('/api/stock', stockRouter)
//
// const wisataPrimer = require("./routes/route.js")
// app.use('/')
app.listen(5001,() => console.log('server started'))
```

And here is my front end (action) code:

```
import {GET_GASTYPE, GET_STOCKTABLE} from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios'

export const getGasType = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/gas')
    .then(res =>
        dispatch({
        type: GET_GASTYPE,
        payload: res.data
    }))
    .catch(err => 
    dispatch((err.response.data, err.response.status))
);
};

export const getGasStatus = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/stock')
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
            type: GET_STOCKTABLE,
            payload: res.data
        }))
    .catch(err => 
        dispatch((err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

Can you guys tell me which part on my code that is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: In your frontend code, whenever you are trying to access `data` from a variable make sure that variable is defined. Possibly here one of the variables either res or response might be undefined after api response which is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in your reducer, check if you are updating correct your state